# Модальное окно через таймер

Tags: javascript, jquery

Возможно ли как то установить таймер  [**этому**](https://codepen.io/romswellparian/full/JdbEvV) плагину pop -up окна чтобы когда user зашел на страницу через к примеру 2 секунды сработал скрипт а не по клику

```
<header><h2>animatedModal.js</h2></header>
<section>
  <p><b>animatedModal.js</b> is a jQuery plugin to create a fullscreen modal with CSS3 transitions. You can use the transitions from <a href="https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/" target="_blank">animate.css</a> or create your own transitions.</p>
  <center>
    <b>DEMOS</b>
    <a id="demo01" href="#animatedModal">01</a>
    <a id="demo02" href="#lightSpeedIn">02</a>
    <a id="demo03" href="#teste">03</a>
    <p>1 <b>animatedIn</b>: 'zoomIn', <b>animatedOut</b>: 'bounceOut'</p>
    <p>2 <b>animatedIn</b>: 'lightSpeedIn', <b>animatedOut</b>: 'bounceOutDown'</p>
    <p>3 <b>animatedIn</b>: 'bounceIn', <b>animatedOut</b>: 'bounceOut'</p>
  </center>
  <p>To more info visit <a href="https://joaopereirawd.github.io/animatedModal.js/" target="_blank">here</a></p>
  <div id="animatedModal">

  <div id="lightSpeedIn">
    <div class="close-lightSpeedIn"><span class="fa fa-close"></span></div>
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="thum">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

CSS

```
body {
  background: #FFF;
  color: #E74B3D;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

a {
  color: #888;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  color: #39BEB9;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

header {
  background: #E74B3D;
  color: #FFF;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 4em 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

p {
  color: #444;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

center {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 40px 0;
}

center > a,
center > a:hover {
  background: #E74B3D;
  border-radius: 100%;
  color: #FFF;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1.65em;
  margin: 6px;
  padding: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

center > b {
  display: block;
  padding: 1em 1em 2em;
}

center p {
  font-size: 13px;
  margin: 10px auto 0;
  padding: 0;
}

section {
  margin: 1em auto;
  max-width: 680px;
}

.modal-content {
  display: block;
  margin: 2em auto;
  max-width: 1000px;
  padding: 10px;
}

[class*="close-"] {
  border: 2px solid;
  border-radius: 100%;
  color: #FFF;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  font-size: 1.75em;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  margin: 1em auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  width: 50px;
}

.thum {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  width: initial;
}

.thum img {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 2px 2px;
  width: 48%;
  -webkit-transition: all .45s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all .45s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .45s ease-in-out;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  .modal-content {
    padding: 0;
  }
  .thum img {
    width: 32%;
    -webkit-transition: all .45s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .45s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .45s ease-in-out;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 340px) {
  .thum img {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto 8px;
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-transition: all .45s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .45s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .45s ease-in-out;
  }
}
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  //demo 02
  $("#demo02").animatedModal({
    modalTarget: 'lightSpeedIn',
    animatedIn: 'lightSpeedIn',
    animatedOut: 'bounceOutDown',
    color: '#39BEB9',
    beforeOpen: function() {
      var children = $(".thumb");
      var index = 0;
      function addClassNextChild() {
        if (index == children.length) return;
        children.eq(index++).show().velocity("transition.slideRightIn", {
          opacity: 1,
          stagger: 450,
          defaultDuration: 100
        });
        window.setTimeout(addClassNextChild, 100);
      }
      addClassNextChild();
    },
    afterClose: function() {
      $(".thumb").hide();
    }
  });


}); // end document ready
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант если ничего не помогло можете эмулировать нажатие на кнопку через определенное время

```
setTimeout(function(){
   $('#demo02').trigger('click');
}, 1000);
```

Comment: как раз других вариантов у меня нет =(